# "Recommendations given to me by someone", is it a little bit wordy?

Tags: word-usage

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/excerpt)

> Here I excerpt from a list of recommendations **given to me by a former boss**.

Is it a little bit wordy? How about this one?

> Here I excerpt from a list of recommendations **from a former boss**.

Comment: That's fine, but personally I find the use of excerpt as a verb to be slightly pretentious. It's like you are trying to show off.  Laypersons may crack a smile when they read it.

Comment: @BruceMurray Thank you. What's the better choice for this particular situation?

Comment: At its most basic: Here is a list of recommendations given by my boss.............but without more context, it's not easy to speculate.

Comment: If you are giving some but not all of your former boss's recommendations. just say "Here are some [of the] recommendations I got from a former boss."  You could include  "of the" if the hearer really needs to know that there are more recommendations than you are telling.